# How do I get all children that fall under a parent in eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In my database, I have a Categories table. Categories can have parent categories, making it a recursive relationship

I also have a products table. Each product falls under a category.

Say, for example, I have a tree that looks like this:

```
Category
    Sub-Category 1
        Sub-Sub-Category 1
            Product 1
            Product 2
            Product 3
            Product 4
        Sub-Sub-Category 2
            Product 5
            Product 6
            Product 7
            Product 8
    Sub-Category 2
        Sub-Sub-Category 3
            Product 9
            Product 10
            Product 11
            Product 12
```

If I do `$SubCategory1->products`, I want it to give me Products 1-8

If I do `$SubSubCategory3->products`, I want it to give me products 9-12

If I do `$Category->products`, I want it to give me all products

Basically, I want the category to give all products that fall under it

Comment: have you checked [Has Many Through](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)?

Comment: there are only 2 tables in this example, how would Has Many Through help me?

Comment: Is `Store` a category too?

Comment: yes, sorry, should have clarified that

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After hoping to find an answer that uses Laravel nicely, I ended up giving up and just writing the code to do what I wanted myself, and it ended up smaller than I anticipated.

```
public function all_products()
{
    $products = [];
    $categories = [$this];
    while(count($categories) > 0){
        $nextCategories = [];
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            $products = array_merge($products, $category->products->all());
            $nextCategories = array_merge($nextCategories, $category->children->all());
        }
        $categories = $nextCategories;
    }
    return new Collection($products); //Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection
}
```

Answer (score 9):

This way works very good:

```
class One extends Model {
    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'parent_id');
    }

    public function grandchildren()
    {
        return $this->children()->with('grandchildren');
    }
}
```

Comment: This still only returns one level deep for me. How do you call it?

Comment: it returns until the leaves; thanks!

Comment: return One::find(3)->grandchildren;

Answer (score 8):

Suppose your Model name is Category

Create a function on Category model

```
public function children() { return $this->hasMany('App\Category', 'parent_id', 'id'); }
```

Using above method on your controller

```
$categories = Category::with('children')->where('parent_id',0)->get();
```

Comment: this gives categories with a particular parent id. 
I want products that have, directly or indirectly, the matching parent

Answer (score 5):

please try the below Has Many Through relation and post the result

```
class Category extends Model
{
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            'App\Product', 'App\Category',
            'parent_id', 'catergory_id', 'id'
        );
    }
}
```

Then you can use `$category->products;` to find your products

Comment: it works 1 level up, but not on anything else. [example](http://i.imgur.com/wy1iJXl.png). In that screenshot, "tray" has 4 products, it's parent has 12 products, and it's parent's parent should have even more than that.

Comment: try logging the query which is generated to understand how the relation ship info in interpreted..

Answer (score 2):

For anyone that is searching for this answer here is a simple solution:

```
class Group extends Model
{
  public function ancestry() 
  {
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Group', 'parent_id')->with('ancestry'); 
  }

  public function descent() 
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Group', 'parent_id')->with('descent'); 
  }
}
```

***ancestry*** function will give you the path to root and ***descent*** will give you all the descendence of that node.

Comment: that's not what the questioner asked

Answer (score 1):

you better use nested sets models. you should use this data structure due to get fastest way to query in mysql with a simple way. with just a parent_id attribute,you don't know how deep your tree is and this make problem in knowing how many join you need.
I offer you this excellent article. [managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)

for those who use laravel framework, I prefer to suggest this amazing package:[Baum](https://github.com/etrepat/baum)

https://stacklearn.ir

Comment: This thing saved me a lot of time. Highly recommend it too.

Answer (score 1):

**ProductCategory.php**

```
public function descent()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\ProductCategory', 'parent_id')->with('descent');
}
```

**Controller**

```
$categories = ProductCategory::with('descent')->get();
```

Desired Tree Was:
[A simple category tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UYk5.png)

Output of `$categories` variable:
[Output in Array Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMHcg.png)

Answer (score 0):

Say $category_id = Category->id and you want a collection of products as children of that category, I would try:

> $products = App\Product::with(['SubSubCategory.SubCategory.Category'=>function($query) use ($category_id) {$query->where('id', $category_id);}])->get();

To be able to do so. You will need your 'one to many' inverse relationships to be as such:

//App\SubCategory

> public function Category(){return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');}

//App\SubSubCategory

> public function Sub_Category(){return $this->belongsTo('App\SubCategory');}

//App\Product

> public function SubSubCategory(){return $this->belongsTo('App\SubSubCategory');}

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

i made managed_by in table (users) and this solution get all unlimited levels of children .

in User Model

```
 public function Childs(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\User', 'managed_by', 'id')->with('Childs');
    }
```

in helpers file (My magic Solution )

```
if (!function_exists('user_all_childs_ids')) {
        function user_all_childs_ids(\App\User $user)
        {
            $all_ids = [];
            if ($user->Childs->count() > 0) {
                foreach ($user->Childs as $child) {
                    $all_ids[] = $child->id;
                    $all_ids=array_merge($all_ids,is_array(user_all_childs_ids($child))?user_all_childs_ids($child):[] );
                }
            }
            return $all_ids;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

### In `Category` model

```
protected static $childrenIds = [];

/**
 * get ids children categories with self id
 * @return array
 */
public function getChildrenIdsAttribute(): array
{
    self::$childrenIds[] = $this->id;
    if ($this->has_children) {
        foreach ($this->children()->active()->get() as $child) {
            $child->children_ids;
        }
    }

    return self::$childrenIds;
}

public function getHasChildrenAttribute()
{
    return (bool)$this->children->count();
}

public function scopeActive($query)
{
    return $query->where('is_active', '=', true);
}

public function children(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'parent_id');
}
```

#### Route

```
Route::get('category/{category}/products', [ProductController::class, 'categoryProducts'])
```

#### Controller

```
public function categoryProducts(Category $category): JsonResponse
{
    $product = Product::whereIn('category_id', $category->children_ids)->get();

    return response()->json($product);
}
```