# How to Access nth Child from Within the Parent Eloquent Model

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have 4 tables with their corresponding models as follows:

```
//Table is applications
class Application extends BaseModel {
    public function bill(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Bill::class,'bill_id');
    }
}
//Table is bills
class Bill extends BaseModel {
    public function groups(){
        return $this->hasMany(Group::class,'group_id');
    }
}
//Table is groups
class Group extends BaseModel {
    public function items(){
        return $this->hasMany(Item::class,'item_id');
    }
}
//Table is items
class Item extends BaseModel {
    // some props
}
```

Every `Application` has `Bill` which is then divided into `Groups`. Each `group` has `Items`. Note that `Items` table is the one that defines `item` and the `amount/unitprice` of each item.

This is what I want:

From within the `Application` Model I want to define a function to return Items. I have tried the followings:

```
class Application extends BaseModel {

    ...

    public function billItems()
    {
        return $this->with('bill.groups.items');
    }

}
```

All I end up getting is:

```
"message": "\Application::billItems must return a relationship instance.",
"exception": "LogicException",
```

What's wrong. What can I do to get it working? I'm using Laravel 5.7

Comment: This will not solve your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38216669/4771024 there might be the answer to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps idea like this will help?

```
class Application extends BaseModel {
    ...
    public function billItems() {
        $items = [];
        $groups = $this->bill->groups()->get();
        foreach ($groups as $group) {
            $items[] = $group->items()->get();
        }

        return collect($items);
    }
}
```

If you like to get detail of bill, groups together with items, you might like to use merge result like Ramūnas Pabrėža suggested in the link.